# How do I create a graph that shows progression over time?

Tags: google-sheets, graph

Firstly, to help explain what I'm looking for. We're a charity delivering services each week to children and young people. At the end of our service, a volunteer will fill out a report form on each child. Some of that form is selecting a number between 1-5 to measure their development, such as 'physical wellbeing' and 'social wellbeing'.

So, I have inherited a large google sheet that contains the above information. Each child is listed multiple times (as people report weekly) and there are columns that display the numbers chosen by the volunteer (1-5) in physical and social wellbeing.

- Is it possible to select that child's info and plot their development over time on a graph?
- **How** do I do that, please? The sheet also contains the date of each service.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168740/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `B1` of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  'Form Responses 1'!A1:N, 
  "select N, toDate(A), P, S 
   where N = 'Jane' ", 
  1 
)
```

...where `A` is the timestamp column, `N` is the name column, and `P` and `S` are the metrics columns you want to plot. Then select columns `C:E` and choose **Insert > Chart**.

To easily switch from child to another, select cell `A1` and choose **Insert > Dropdown**. In the **Data validation rules** sidebar, choose **Criteria > Dropdown (from a range)** and put `'Form Responses 1'!N2:N` in the range box. Then modify the `where N is 'Jane' ",` clause of the `query()` formula like this:

`where N = '" & A1 & "' ",`

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for your reply. I am being very stupid and not understanding- could you help?

My sheet looks like this example:
Date  Name Active Wellbeing Social Wellbeing
02/10/2021 Child 1 5 4
09/10/2021 Child 1 5 4
16/10/2021 Child 1 4 3
23/10/2021 Child 1 5 4
20/11/2021 Child 1 5 5
06/11 /2021 Child 1 4 3
11/12/2021 Child 1 5 3
22/01/2022 Child 1 5 4
05/02/2022 Child 1 5 3

Could you help me input that into the answer you gave me? I want it to plot Child 1's progress (or not) for all dates onto a chart.

Thank you

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer. Do not post sample data in a comment. If you do not want to share a sample spreadsheet, [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168740/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Comment: There are lots of other children's names (with similar dates) in the sheet and I need to do same for all of them.

Comment: The `query()` formula in the answer gets the metrics for all names in column `N`. Make your [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168740/edit) answerable by inserting a table or by sharing a sample spreadsheet.